# C: How to mount a regular filesystem created with mkfs using mount(2)?

Tags: c, unix, mount

This is how I made my "regular" filesystem:

```
$ touch container
$ mkfs.ext4 container 20000
```

How can I mount it using C function [mount(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mount) ?

Actually mount tells me :

> Block device required

Is there a way to create a filesystem in C ?

Comment: You need to make a loopback device, but this depends on what UNIX you are using. What UNIX are you using?

Comment: @FUZxxl: it's pretty much gotta be a linux box becasue of mkfs.ext4

Comment: @Joshua FreeBSD also has that as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `mount` library call does not set up a loop device. In order to mount your container, you would have needed to pass `-o loop` to the `mount` command, which effectively includes what `losetup` does (i.e. makes `/dev/loopN` point to your file and mounts that). When using the library call, you need to simulate that, i.e. you need to set up a loop device first.

To determine exactly what you want need to do, try:

```
strace mount -t ext4 -o loop container /mnt
```

and have a look at the system calls. You can see that what's happening is that first it makes a loop device (e.g. `/dev/loop0` using the system call equivalent of `losetup`), then it mounts that loop device.

Here are the key lines from the `strace` output:

First allocate the loop device:

```
stat("/dev/loop", 0x7fffe90b00b0)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/loop0", O_RDONLY)            = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(7, 0), ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, LOOP_GET_STATUS, {number=39736224, offset=0x6f726763, encrypt_type=0x732f7075 /* LO_CRYPT_??? */, encrypt_key_size=1702130553, flags=LO_FLAGS_READ_ONLY|LO_FLAGS_AUTOCLEAR|LO_FLAGS_PARTSCAN|0x63206460, name="group rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd 0 0", encrypt_key="s 0 0\0\0e-agent.devices 0 0\0\0\320\177\0\0", ...}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
close(3)                                = 0
open("/home/amb/so/container", O_RDWR)  = 3
open("/dev/loop0", O_RDWR)              = 4
readlink("/home", 0x7fffe90adfa0, 4096) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
readlink("/home/amb", 0x7fffe90adfa0, 4096) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
readlink("/home/amb/so", 0x7fffe90adfa0, 4096) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
readlink("/home/amb/so/container", 0x7fffe90adfa0, 4096) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
ioctl(4, LOOP_SET_FD, 0x3)              = 0
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(4, LOOP_SET_STATUS64, {offset=0, number=0, flags=LO_FLAGS_AUTOCLEAR, file_name="/home/amb/so/container", ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, LOOP_GET_STATUS64, {offset=0, number=0, flags=LO_FLAGS_AUTOCLEAR, file_name="/home/amb/so/container", ...}) = 0
```

and only then do a `mount`:

```
mount("/dev/loop0", "/mnt", "ext4", MS_MGC_VAL, NULL) = 0
```

I would however advise you to shell out to `mount` unless you have a good reason not to. This ensures `/etc/mtab` etc. is maintained.

Answer (score 1):

As a followup to abligh's answer, the code for setting up a loop device is

```
int device = open(device_path, O_RDWR);
/* omitting error checking on device for clarity */
char buf[20];
int success = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 999999999) {
    sprintf(buf, "/dev/loop%d", i);
    int h = open(buf, O_RDWR);
    if (h > -1) {
        int r= ioctl(h, LOOP_SET_FD, device);
        close(h);
        if (!r) {
           success = 1;
           break;
        }
    } else if (errno == ENOENT)
        break;
}
if (!success) {
     /* no more free loop devices or you're not root */
}
```